# Apache 301 redirect, based on page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My current redirection looks like this:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Is there a way I can modify this to redirect to execute on ALL pages except /noredirect.php?

Answer (score 2):

Add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/noredirect.php
```

Comment: Thanks, although this does not seem to work:  
`RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]  
 RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^/noredirect.php  
 rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`

Comment: I guess I forgot a `%`, sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, not sure how I missed that.  I added it and still no luck, though I think this is very close. . .I'm gonna try to find some apache docs on this sort of thing